# View PPT & PDF on Android

Tags: android, pdf, powerpoint

Can we view PDF & PPT document on Android phone with the help of any software ?
Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: android.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ppt you can use: [Document to go](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/)

For pdf you can use: [AndPdf](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could also convert them to html and use the embedded webkit browser to view them